# JavaFX: How to keep the distance between two polygons constant when one/both of them are resized (scaled)?

Tags: java, javafx, binding, shapes, hexagonal-tiles

I have a honeycomb of hexagons in my GUI and their size keeps changing dynamically. I need to find a way to scale these shapes simultaneoulsy without overlapping each other.

I have figured out that the distance between the edges must remain constant but that's about it. I really need help translating this into code. Any help would much appreciated !!
I am currently using Scene Builder. I tried to bind the distance between the centers of the polygons to one of the polygons. Here is my code (which doesn't work) :

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root ;
    @FXML
    private Polygon poly1;
    @FXML
    private Polygon poly2;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    DoubleProperty distanceProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    ChangeListener<Number> changeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(poly1.getLayoutX(), poly1.getLayoutY());
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(poly2.getLayoutX(), poly2.getLayoutY());
        distanceProperty.set(p1.distance(p2));
    };
    poly1.layoutXProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    poly2.layoutXProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    poly1.layoutYProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    poly2.layoutYProperty().addListener(changeListener);

    poly1.layoutYProperty().bind(distanceProperty);
    poly1.layoutXProperty().bind(distanceProperty);

    // changing the size of poly1
    double initialScaleX = poly1.getScaleX();
    double initialScaleY = poly1.getScaleY();
    poly1.setScaleX(initialScaleX*2.0);
    poly1.setScaleY(initialScaleY*2.0);
}
}
```

Comment: Rather than the distance between the edges, you should look at the distance between the centers and their changes to radius as they grow/shrink. You basically need to either shrink the adjacent hexagon's size at the same rate it's neighbor grows or offset it's center position by the amount the neighbor's shape displaces with it's changes.

Comment: Share some code don't be afraid.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs  I have included the code above. I am using Tim Hunter 's idea to offset the neighbor's center position using binding but I am unsure as to how to go about it. Could you please tell me if I am on the correct path?

Comment: @TimHunter could you please look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong. I am not sure if I have to use binding or a different technique to establish a relationship between the polgons' center's.

Comment: Please post [mre]